# mfp server configuration in maven web application

Tags: angular, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I have gone through following FirstMobile developer guide for web application development.

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/web-tutorials/

My understanding is there are 2 ways to create web application. Those are 1. using maven and 2. Using Node.js. We can configure mfp server details in proxy.js if we use node.js. But I didn’t found mfp server configuration in maven application.

Can anyone tell where we need configure mfp server details in maven web application?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an adapter, you first need to download and install Maven. Go to the Apache Maven website and follow the instructions how to download and install Maven.

Comment: Welcome to SO. IMHO, the OP problem is not missing a Maven installation but instead the need to know, how to configure mfp using Maven.